# Scan for substring and Ignore case sensitivity using Regex

Tags: ruby, regex, string, substring

I have a very long text and I'm trying to scan it in order to find few words in it.
I'm looking for a function that will do the trick but will disregard lower or upper case sensitivity.

**Very important:** I can't change the string to lower or upper case! It is a post app and if I will change it, it will be tricky to roll back.

Example:

```
str = "According to a new report from TechCrunch, Apple has acquired the photo technology startup SnappyLabs. The company is a one-man development team known for creating the SnappyCam app."

word = "the"

str.scan(/word/) # need to find "the" and "The"
```

**UPDATE**

How to get the string index of the first appearance of the word?

In case someone else needs it, by using `str =~ (/word/i)`(thanks to @steenslag)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
str = "According to a new report from TechCrunch, Apple has acquired the photo technology startup SnappyLabs. The company is a one-man development team known for creating the SnappyCam app."

word = "the"

str.scan(/#{word}/i) # need to find "the" and "The"
```

The "i" after the regexp makes it case-ignoring.

Comment: Is there a way of getting the str index of the first appearance of the word?

Comment: Yes, `use str =~ (/word/i)` (not tested).

Comment: @AHK any alternative?